# Saved to send buffer because there are 0 open requests (mod_bosh with Prosody)

Tags: xmpp

I am using prosody chat server with mod_bosh module. For some reason when using one of the accounts, prosody is taking 100% of the core on which it is running and does not respond anymore.

In the debug log I have the following lines:

```
Nov 06 07:58:38 boshf9327776-e16a-4204-b73c-fee65cd9b796    debug   Received[c2s]: <iq id='79:sendIQ' type='get' to='2c335366455a21082165e666a6e30466@myserver.io'>
Nov 06 07:58:39 mod_bosh    debug   Saved to send buffer because there are 0 open requests
Nov 06 07:58:39 mod_bosh    debug   There are now 56 things in the send_buffer
Nov 06 07:58:39 mod_bosh    debug   BOSH stanza received: <iq id='80:sendIQ' type='get' to='a6824b1baa40644395480a5afa6038f6@myserver.io'>
```

As soon as the user is connected these lines appear continuously and there more and more "things" in the send buffer. It looks somehow like an infinite loop.

Does anybody know why this is happening? And also does anybody know what is an "open request"? Can I configure it to have more open requests?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, Prosody developer here. It might take some back-and-forth to debug your issue, and I'm not sure StackOverflow is the appropriate medium for this. Feel free to (re)join our chatroom or post to our mailing list and we'll do our best to get to the bottom of your issue :)

Comment: Hi MattJ, thanks for your help today. In a few words: a. we updated our server to the latest version (we made a build on CentOS) but performance is the same. As you mentioned, an important amount of vCards requests seem to arrive at once and are queued. However it takes more than 30 secs to a 2,6 Ghz dedicated core to deal with this query. In the meantime the chat server is not really responding anymore. We are continuing to investigate.